# Pull form data into nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, nodemailer

I have a form and I'm using nodemailer to send a test email to myself
In the "to" and "subject" I want to place the email thats inputed into the form that way when the user clicks submit it sends them an email. I've tried `req.email` and `req.body.email` and have not been successful.

```
app.get("/teachers/payment", function (req, res) {
    res.render("teacher_payment.ejs")
});

app.post("/registration", function (req, res) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail'
        , auth: {
            user: 'user'
            , pass: 'pass'
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'zyyangch@gmail.com'
        , to: 'req.body.email'
        , subject: req.body.email
        , text: 'It works! ✔', //plaintext body
        html: '<a href="http://localhost:3000/complete-profile">Click Here</a>'
    };

    //send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
})
```

Any fix for this?

Comment: Are you using `body-parser` middleware?
If yes, what do you see when you log `req.body`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value from the email key, without quotation marks:

```
 var mailOptions = {
    from: 'zyyangch@gmail.com'
    , to: req.body.email
    , subject: req.body.email
    , text: 'It works! ✔', //plaintext body
    html: '<a href="http://localhost:3000/complete-profile">Click Here</a>'
};
```